# Template function parameter T deduction misunderstanding

Tags: c++14

I am very new to C++ and I was trying out templating to understand how it works. I have a template function that accepts an argument of type T. The problem that I am facing is that T's type is determined at runtime depending on the value of T and the compiler throws an error because it determines the type without considering the if-else-if-else block.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        void setInt(int x) {}
        void setString(string y) {} // copy string object
};

void f1() {
    cout << "break" << endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void f1(T arg, Args... args) {

    string _type(typeid(arg).name());

    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    cout << _type << endl;

    MyClass c1;

    if( _type.compare("i") == 0 ) {
        c1.setInt(arg);
    } else if ( _type.compare("PKc") == 0 ) {
        //c1.setString(arg);
    }

    f1(args...);
};

int main() {

    f1(7, 3.3, "asd", 0xa1);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void f1(T, Args ...) [with T = const char*; Args = {int}]’:
prog.cpp:30:4:   recursively required from ‘void f1(T, Args ...) [with T = double; Args = {const char*, int}]’
prog.cpp:30:4:   required from ‘void f1(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {double, const char*, int}]’
prog.cpp:35:24:   required from here
prog.cpp:25:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   c1.setInt(arg);
             ^~~
prog.cpp:6:19: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void MyClass::setInt(int)’
   void setInt(int x) {}
               ~~~~^
```

https://ideone.com/the4AP (The link to online compiler)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a template function here. Just define two regular functions with the same name, one taking an `int` and the other a `string`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, but what if f1() accepts a variadic arguments of different types?

Comment: Show a concrete example of what you have in mind.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, please refer to my modified post.

Comment: You might be accessing `T`'s type at runtime via `typeid`, but it is 100% determined by the compiler at compile time. C++17 introduces `if constexpr`, which would allow you to do something similar to what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
void f1_helper(int arg, MyClass* c) {
  c->setInt(arg);
}

void f1_helper(string arg, MyClass* c) {
  c->setString(arg);
}

template<typename... Args>
void f1(Args... args) {
   MyClass c1;
   auto _ = {(f1_helper(args, &c1), 0) ...};
}
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/GJAP23672)

Comment: what does auto _ = {(f1_helper(args, &c1), 0) ...}; mean?

Comment: Nice. Maybe is the case to add a zero, declaring `_` (`auto _ = { 0, (f1_helper(args, &c1), 0) ... };`), just to avoid problems when the `args...` list is empty.

Comment: @user2176499 This is a poor man's [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). C++17 introduces a nicer syntax, but you tagged your question C++14, so a workaround is needed. This declares a variable, named `_` (which is a valid identifier), of type `std::initializer_list<int>`, initialized with a list of as many zeros as there are `args`. Each initializer, as a side effect by way of a comma operator, calls `f1_helper(args, &c1)` on one `arg`, which is the point of the exercise. In C++17, you could just write `(f1_helper(args, &c1), ...);`